# How to split string without defined delimeter

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
bar = "Bar 01/12/15"
foo = "Foo02/15/87"
```

How can a split those variables so that resulting array contains:

```
bar_array = ["Bar", "01/12/15"]
foo_array = ["Foo","02/15/87"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = /(?<=[[:alpha:]]) ?(?=\d)/

"Bar 01/12/15".split(r)
  #=> ["Bar", "01/12/15"]
"Foo02/15/87".split(r)
  #=> ["Foo", "02/15/87"]
```

The regular expression reads

- match a letter in a positive lookbehind
- match 0 or 1 spaces
- match a digit in a positive lookahead

Answer (score 1):

If your string will always have that *dd/mm/yy* format **at the end**, you can create a method that takes the last 8 characters from the string and return both values (remaining string and date) as an array, something like this:

```
def to_array(string)
  date = string[-8..-1]
  [string.delete(date).strip, date]
end

to_array(bar)
#=> ["Bar", "01/12/15"]

to_array(foo)
# => ["Foo", "02/15/87"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the provided string (as in your examples):

1. Contains one word and a date (with zero or more spaces between them)
2. The date is formed with 8 characters (i.e. `##/##/##` format)
3. The date is at the end of the string

You could do the following:

```
bar.sub(/(.{8})\z/, ' \1').split
#=> ["Bar", "01/12/15"]
```

- `sub(/(.{8})\z/, ' \1')` will add a space before the date
- `split` will split the string where a space (or more) is found

Answer (score 0):

regex works

```
"a,b'c d".split /\s|'|,/
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

here's some documentation on regular expressions

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_regular_expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `bar = "Bar 01/12/15"` includes a space `" "`

If variable `foo` also should include a space as `foo = "Foo 02/15/87"`

You can just use `.split` on `bar` without entering a delimiter.

It will return `["Bar", "01/12/15"]`(remember to set your variable `bar_array` equal to it.)

However if you have a string like `"1,2,3"`, you would need to enter a delimiter `","` : `"1,2,3".split(",")` in order to get `["1","2","3"]`. Otherwise, it will return `["1,2,3"]`

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex to match the date form and whatever is before it:

```
bar = "Bar 01/12/15"
foo = "Foo02/15/87"
pattern = /^(.*?)([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/

bar.scan(pattern).flatten.map(&:strip)
=> ["Bar", "01/12/15"]

foo.scan(pattern).flatten.map(&:strip)
=> ["Foo", "02/15/87"]
```

Comment: You could remove any non-wanted spaces (as in `"Bar "`) adding `.map(&:strip)`.